# Google speech recognition offline use

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I just read an article that google created a speech recognition that works offline on Android.

Is there a way to use that in my project that is not based on Android?

I'm sure that I'm not the first one who thinks about to use it in none Android projects, but I couldn't find anyone who did it and put it into the world wide web.

Comment: google speech recognition in offline mode give lot of errors ,as far as i know in android

Comment: as far it still does what it should then I don't mind the errors. it's just nice to have a faster way that is not depending on a internet connection to the google speech recognition api

Comment: @Mr.Tr33 did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Redman which problems. Is it possible to use that?